# OpenGL ARB_framebuffer_object extension is not available

Tags: qt, opengl, 3d

I'm having an app that processes some DSL and draws a page. That app is qt-based. I need to work with DSL not with QT. When processing that DSL an app throws the following error

```
OpenGL ARB_framebuffer_object extension is not available
```

My laptop is rather old. I'm running Windows Vista, my gfx card is ATI Radeon HD 3200 Graphics. I tried to install `ATI Radeon HD 4850 X2 Catalyst Driver 9.1 WHQL Vista` and `Hydravision` pack for Vista and that did not help.

Can someone tell me whether I can fix the problem on my laptop and how?

Comment: This error means that your drivers don't support that extension, though looking at the [spec page](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_object.txt) you should only need drivers capable of OpenGL 1.1 (which is really old). Is this an app that you've used before for a similar purpose? Ie, is this the first time this app would have had a chance to throw this error? What app are you using? It seems like the app is the major problem, since I assume you're not actually writing any OpenGL code involving ARB_framebuffer_object.

Comment: @Hydronium,yes you're right I'm not dealing with OpenGL. I have not used the app for similar purpose. So what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. Since you've already updated your drivers I doubt the issue is (directly) related to OpenGL. If it's entirely the app's fault, Stack Overflow can't really help because we can't see the code or anything about it which might be causing the problem.

Comment: Are you actually writing code as part of/for the app or are you just "using" the app?

Comment: @Hydronium You didn't read the spec page properly, it says the extension requires OpenGL v1.1, but it was brought into the Core for v3.0 (https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object).  The OPs hardware only supports up to v2.0 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Mobility_Radeon_HD_3xxx_Series).

Comment: @cmannett85 Regardless of it being in the core spec the ARB extension is what he's using, not the core function. Maybe I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty straightforward: your hardware just doesn't support the required extension.

<sub>And it's common knowledge software developers hate hardware problems :)</sub>